# Execute Ruby Function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my index view I am looking to add a button that will execute a function called `myFunction(myArg)`. This function is located in `behaviours/myRubyFile.rb`. How can I create a button that executes that function with a particular argument.

EDIT:
Now I am getting a new error

`The action 'my_func' could not be found for FunctionsController`

However there is a function `my_func` defined in FunctionsController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you'd want to send a request to the server from that button, so the server runs myFunction. To achieve this follow these steps:

1 - make sure behaviours/myRubyFile.rb defines a module:

```
module MyRubyModule
  def myFunction(arg)
    #Your logic here
  end
end
```

2 - define a route in routes.rb:

```
match '/my_func' => "functions#my_func"
```

3 - define FunctionsController:

```
class FunctionsController < ApplicationController
  include MyRubyModule

  def my_func
    arg = params[:arg]
    myFunction(arg)
  end
end
```

4 - create a button in the view to send the request to the server:

```
<%= button_to "Button", {:action => "my_func", :controller => "functions", :arg => "YOUR ARG HERE"} %>
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should do the trick.

EDIT: added `:arg => "YOUR ARG HERE"` to the route (Thnx nzifnab)

Comment: I am confused as to how `:controller => "functions"` related to `my_func` and how the arguments are being passed.

Comment: The args will be sent via `params` in the controller.  I think it sounds like you need a tutorial on the basics of Rails and how a controller receives requests from the view.  Have you read the guides?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: To add @Erez Rabih, You need to send `:arg` in that button request.  So the options sent to button_to should be `{:action => "my_func", :controller => "functions", :arg => "Some Arg"}`

Comment: I see how the `params` send the args to the `myFunction`, however I don't see how the view is passing the arguments to the `my_func`  EDIT: Nevermind I see it now Thanks